# Magento 2.1 Category URL Key

Tags: magento

In the release note it says "The Search Engine Optimization fieldset no longer displays Category url_key." So my questions is where can I find the category url_key now?

I have a category named "Polarised" and when I tried to display the category using /polarised it returns 404. This never considered an issue in version 1 but I'm not sure what happened in the 2.1 release, appreciate your comments, thanks.

Comment: In case someone else running into the same issue, here is how I figured it out:
1) Regarding category url key not displaying in Search Engine Optimisation section: This is because I didn't use default root category, all my categories were actually root categories. When I create a default root category and nest all my product categories under it, then I can see my subcategories now have URL Key field.
2) Why all my category product pages returns 404? This is because of Magento 2 URL suffix (.html), when I change it from /polarised to /polarised.html, it worked!